# Can I have Gmail notify me when it is unable to retrieve mail from my other accounts?

Tags: gmail, account-management, notifications

Is there a way to get Gmail to notify me when it is unable to retrieve mail from my other accounts?

I have Gmail checking several accounts (under *Settings → Accounts & Import*), but on occasion it fails to connect to a web server (usually because that server is down).

If I go into *Settings → Accounts & Import* there is a red warning message that it failed, but I may not notice this for hours or days.

Is there any way to get some kind of warning on the main page of Gmail? It could be a message box or an email.

Comment: Good question - this has bugged me for a while. I get my old dial-up ISP's email (haven't used the dial-up in 5 years!) through my GApps account and it was failing for 2 months before I noticed!

Comment: Great question - this happens to me all the time with my University account.

Answer (score 1):

It may be useful a [apps-script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/) that daily monitors the dates of the last messages received in a label associated with an imported account . For instance:

- create  al label for each imported account.
- daily check this labels and get the date of last message received.
- Send yourself an email if the date is too far from now.

Answer (score -1):

It does!

http://www.flickr.com/photos/mbrochh/4754756093/sizes/o/

Comment: -1 That only appears if you have the Labs "Refresh POP accounts" switched on and have manually refreshed. It does not appear after a failed automatic, background POP download.